# How to get the value of textbox and use in query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I used $_POST to get the value of order_id but it didn't quiet get right away. I need first to click Button "Show Food" or any button (As seen in the photo below) to popup the table I want to output.

if I change the WHERE order_id=$order_id to WHERE order_id=724 it will popup right away the value of that number (724) BUT it is the output of ALL my order in the food table. So my problem is how can I output the right output for specific order_id?

Example I have 2 order order_id 1 and order_id 2, the value of 1 is burger and pizza and the value of 2 is salad and sandwich , So when I click the 1 the value of that food table is burger and pizza only and then when I click the 2 the value should be salad and sandwich not burger and pizza.

[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TqCR.png)

[This is after I click Show Food or any button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir7kk.png)

I hope you understand my explanation and I hope for your help guys, Thanks!

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that this is inside my ordermodal. Just to be clear

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="order_id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Order ID</label>
  <div class="col-lg-3"> 
    <input type="text" input style="width:500px" class="form-control" name="ORDER_ID" id="ORDER_ID" placeholder="" value="" required="required" readonly> 
  </div>
</div>

<?php 
  $order_id = trim(addslashes($_POST['ORDER_ID']));
  $sql = "SELECT food_name, special_request, quantity, amount 
          FROM cart_tbl
          WHERE order_id=$order_id";
  $result = mysqli_query(connection2(), $sql);
?>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr> 
      <th>Food</th>
      <th>Special Request</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Amount</th> 
    </tr>
 </thead> 
 <?php
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       ?>
       <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row["food_name"];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row["special_request"];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row["quantity"];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row["amount"];?></td>
       </tr>
       <?php
     }
   }
?>

</table>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="submit" input 
     style="background-color: #FF0000; color:white; float:left" 
     name="showFood" id="showFood" class="btn btn-primary" 
     onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to see food order?')){return false;}" > Show Food
  </button>
  <button type="submit" input 
     style="background-color: #4CAF50; color:white" 
     name="submitDelivered" id="submitDelivered" 
     class="btn btn-primary" 
     onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to deliver order?')){return false;}" > Delivered 
  </button>
  <button type="submit" input 
     style="background-color: #0000FF; color: white" 
     name="submitAccept" id="submitAccept" class="btn btn-primary" 
     onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to accept order?')){return false;}"  <?php if($_POST['order_status']="Accepted"): ?>.disabled <?php endif ?>> Accept 
  </button>
  <button type="button" style="background-color: #FFFF00;color: black" 
     class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" 
     data-target="#myDropdown"> Send 
  </button> 
  <button type="submit" input 
     style="background-color: #f44336; color: white" 
     name="submitCancel" class="btn btn-danger" 
     onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel order?')){return false;}">Cancel
  </button> 
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like your MySQL query is failing. Try `var_dump($sql)` to ensure the query is well formatted and that the value of `$_POST['order_id']` exists in the database.

Comment: @Cobolt Yes it exists in my database

Comment: According to your error message, `$_POST['ORDER_ID']` is not defined and therefore the SQL query you are generating is invalid and the result of `mysqli_query` is `false` instead of an instance of `mysqli_result` . Try `$_POST['order_id']`, it is probably case-sensitive. If that doesn't work, do `var_dump($_POST);` to ensure that the `order_id` variable exists in the `$_POST` array when the form is posted.

Comment: @Coboit it exists but the value will get after I click a button. Why thats happening?

Comment: The initial value of `$_POST['ORDER_ID']` is not set. The request that loads the modal must send the value

Comment: @Cobolt so how can I send the value bro?

Comment: How does the modal open? You might need to use javascript

Comment: @Cobolt By clicking a button view order bro.

Comment: When you look at the html for the vieworder button say in the onclick attribute? Something like onclick="openmodal()"? It is probably using javascript. You need to make the modal load a page like showmodal.php?order_id=5 and then use $_GET['order_id']

Comment: @Cobolt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504705/how-to-get-the-value-from-other-page I included there all needed codes,sorry I didn't include it here cuz I think its good to have a new question to be more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

are you using ajax? if yes, you need to show us your ajax code.

ie your $.post(url, data) <-- some thing like this. i am afraid the problem is on your ajax code. make sure that you have included ORDER_ID in the data.

here is more example:

```
var order_id = $('input[name="ORDER_ID"]').val();
var data: {ORDER_ID: order_id};
var url = 'http://your-URL';
$.post(url, data).done(function(result){console.log(result))})
```

Comment: Nah dude, right now it doesn't have ajax, because of this error I can move to next.